# How do I find solutions for this kind of problems?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

Can someone give me a small hint about solving problems like this? Sadly I can't present my own work because I have zero clue how to start(well, I did find a solution for a simillar problem with c++ and bruteforce but thats irrelevant here). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a quite well known puzzle by to Conway (e.g. mentioned here https://www.quantamagazine.org/three-math-puzzles-inspired-by-john-horton-conway-20201015/, this also links to a solution). Basically you wanna look through the different digits using modular arithmetic. E.g. for the ten-digit number to be divisble by 10 it has to end in $0$ (since $\sum_{j=0}^9 a_{j+1} 10^j = a_1 \mod 10$), by considering divisbility by $5$ you can infer that $a_6=5$ and you can continue similarly. My solution (it's in German though) can be found here https://github.com/SV-97/Denksport/blob/main/paper.pdf